# Incremental Data Storage

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, time-series, amazon-redshift

I have time series daily data which I run a model on. The model runs in Spark.

I only want to run the model daily, and append the results to the historic results. It is important to have a 'merged single data source' containing historical data for the model to run successfully.

I have to use an AWS service to store the results. If I store in S3, I will end up storing backfill + 1 file per day (too many files). If I store in Redshift, it doesn't merge + upsert, therefore becoming complicated. The customer facing data is in Redshift, so dropping the table and reloading daily is not an option.

I am not sure how to cleverly (defined as minimal cost and subsequent processing) store the incremental data without re-processing everything daily to get a single file.

Comment: "If I store in Redshift, it doesn't merge + upsert, therefore becoming complicated." - can you expand on this? Why are you unable to create the insert/update logic in Redshift?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is still your best shot. Since your job doesn't seems need to be accessed on a real-time fashion, it's more of a rolling data set.

If you are worried about the amount of file it generates, there is at least 2 things you can do:

1. S3 object lifecycle management
   You can define your objects to be removed or transition to another storage class(cheaper) after x days.
   More examples: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html
2. S3 notification
   Basically you can set up a listener in your S3 bucket, 'listening for' all the objects that match your specified prefix and suffix, to trigger other AWS services. One easy thing you can do is to trigger a Lambda, do your processing and then you can do whatever you would like.
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-event-notifications.html

Use S3 as your database whenever it's possible. It's damn cheap and it's AWS's backbone.

Comment: The trouble is that we have a lot of 'databases' going into the model. So you end up with subfolders with hundreds of files (one per day) and it becomes very messy. If a job fails one day, that file is missing, and screws up the Redshift load. Also, in S3, you still end up having to 'drop the table' I think for Redshift (which will contain all historical data, therefore moving out of S3 will be hard). I strongly prefer S3 in general, just trying to understand how to make it work. What is the 'cheaper' storage option vs S3?

Comment: There is 4 storage classes here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html. I don't think it is that messy as you think because AWS use that convention too. e.g, one of my access log bucket(I enabled access logging for one of my application LB) looks like: s3://mybucket/AWSLogs/123456/elasticloadbalancing/us-east-1/2018/08/20/123456_alb.log.gz. It looks messy to human, but if you use a good folder naming scheme like above for your folders, S3 event notification + lambda or whatever should do the work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also switch to an ETL. A very efficient one, which is OpenSource, specialized in BigData, fully automatizable and easy to use is the [Pentaho Data Integrator](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pentaho/files/Data%20Integration/).

It comes equipped with ready made plugins for S3, Redshift (and others), and there is a single step to compare with previous values. From my experience it runs pretty fast. Plus it works for you during the night and sends you a morning mail saying every thing went OK (or not).

Note to the moderators: this is a agnostic point of view, I could have recommended many others, but this one seams the most suited for the OP's need.

Comment: Thanks! I found this which may be useful for future readers: https://sonra.io/2018/01/01/using-apache-airflow-to-build-a-data-pipeline-on-aws/